# Confusion on Energies of absorbed and emitted photons

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, atomic-physics, atoms

My physics teacher shouted this atleast 3 times yesterday, 'a photon can be absorbed only when it's energy is EXACTLY equal to the energy difference between the energy states'

So my understanding is,  for any excitation of electrons (in Bohrs H model of atom) there is a specified energy given by the formula $E =-13.6×(\frac{1}{n_f^2}-\frac{1}{n_i^2})$ where $n$ represents energy states.

My 1st doubt

> Okay so the energy of photons must be EXACTLY EQUAL TO E for the
> excitation to take place. Even if the energy of photons is GREATER
> than E, the excitation hmmmm, won't take place?

My 2nd doubt

> So incase of a successful excitation of electrons due to incident
> photons, again photons are emitted due to that excitation right (which
> in some scenarios impart color etc.)? So it's the energy of the
> emitted photos same as the magnitude of E?

Comment: Both are correct.

Answer (score 7):

> Okay so the energy of photons must be EXACTLY EQUAL TO E for the
> excitation to take place. Even if the energy of photons is GREATER
> than E, the excitation hmmmm, won't take place?

In the first approximation this is correct, and you are probably not expected to know more at this point.

However, the reality is more complex, and two things are immediately worth pointing out:

- **level broadening** there are various mechanisms that result in "broadening" of the energy levels, which means that there is a finite range of photon energies that may be absorbed and emitted by any particular pair of atomic levels. One could think of it as a frequency range of width $\Gamma$, although in reality the broadening is usually described by a smooth curve peaked on the transition energy $E_{nm}$ (as given by the equation in the OP.) The mechanisms causing broadening are interaction with vacuum fluctuations, Doppler shift (when averaging over many atoms), etc.
- **Raman scattering** If the energy of a photon is greater than the spacing between energy levels, it still can be absorbed, in a process called [*Raman scattering*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raman_scattering). However, this process has much lower probability than the absorption of a photon that matches the level spacing - in the sense that it is much harder to observe, given the same light intensity. Moreover, photons withe energies either greater pr smaller than the level spacing are also scattered, in the process of [*Rayleigh scattering*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_scattering) - this one is also less probable, and plays role at very high light intensities... the most notable case being the blue color of the sky.

> So incase of a successful excitation of electrons due to incident
> photons, again photons are emitted due to that excitation right (which
> in some scenarios impart color etc.)? So it's the energy of the
> emitted photos same as the magnitude of E?

Indeed, excited level will eventually lose its energy ("relax") by emitting a photon of the energy corresponding to the level spacing. Alternatively, it can be excited to an even higher state - if we provide a photon of a suitable energy fast enough (before relaxation happens.) One may also observe more complicated scattering, like anti-Srokes Raman process.

[image]

Comment: indeed  atomic transitions are complicated , as the OP might realize reading the link http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Atomic/broaden.html